# How to check whether an object exists a List using Streams

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-stream

I have to create a result list by adding objects.

Here is my code.

```
private ArrayList<Car> carsInStore ;

public boolean addCarToStore(String type, String model, String color,
                                    int maxSpeed,int year,String plateNumber) {
    for (Car car : carsInStore) {
        if (car.getPlateNumber()==plateNumber) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            carsInStore.add(new Car(type, model, color, maxSpeed,
                                        year, plateNumber));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to check if a *car* with the given `plateNumber` already exist within the `ArrayList`, if it exists, then a *new car* will not be added.

I'd like to perform the check via Java streams.

I'm using Java 11.

Comment: if its a single method call with a single plateNumber then it makes no sense of using stream.
if you have a list of plateNumber and wants to add them all to ArrayList<Car> carsInStore checking with the condition you have mentioned then using stream makes sense.

Comment: Your string comparison is incorrect.

Comment: I noticed . Thanks for the help

Comment: If platenumber is an important value for finding objects, I would consider using Map<String, Car> where the key is the plate number. Map already contains extra functions to handle scenarios where an object either does or does not exist for a given key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rewrite your method using stream, as suggested in the comments, you could check with a stream if a `Car` with the given plate number already exists within the `List`; if it does not, then you could add it to `carsInStore`.

Also, to check whether two `String` are equal you need to use the `equals` method. The `==` operator checks the content of the confronted variables, in case of references their content corresponds to the memory address of the object they point, not the actual value they represent.

```
private ArrayList<Car> carsInStore;

public boolean addCarToStore(String type, String model, String color, int maxSpeed, int year, String plateNumber) {
    if (carsInStore.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getPlateNumber().equals(plateNumber))
        .findFirst()
        .isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    carsInStore.add(new Car(type, model, color, maxSpeed, year, plateNumber));
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findAny()`. Refer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-stream-findany-with-examples/).

> Stream findAny() returns an Optional (a container object which may or may not contain a non-null value) describing some element of the stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty. The behavior of Stream 'findAny()' operation is explicitly non-deterministic, it is free to select any element in the stream. Multiple invocations on the same source may not return the same result.

Use `Optional` class to check for null pointer exceptions.

```
Optional<Car> result =  carsInStore.stream().filter(c -> c.getPlateNumber().equals(plateNumber)).findAny();
    if(!result.isPresent()){
      // your logic 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. You want to replace the `for each` loop in the `addCarToStore` method with a streaming API implementation:

```java
Optional<Car> existingCar = carsInStore
    .stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getPlateNumber().equals(plateNumber))
    .findAny();

if (existingCar.isEmpty()) {
    carsInStore.add(new Car(type, model, color, maxSpeed, year, plateNumber));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To produce a boolean result if a car with the given property already exists, you need to use [`anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) operation, which expects a *predicate* - a function representing a boolean condition.

Opposed to `findFirst()` and `findAny()` which are useful when you need to obtain an object as a result, `anyMatch()` it returns `boolean` value and there's no need to interpret the optional result.

```
public boolean addCarToStore(String type, String model, String color,
                             int maxSpeed, int year, String plateNumber) {
    
    boolean alreadyExist = carsInStore.stream()
        .anyMatch(car -> car.getPlateNumber().equals(plateNumber));
    
    if (!alreadyExist) {                
        carsInStore.add(new Car(type, model, color, maxSpeed,
                                year, plateNumber));
    }
    
    return alreadyExist;
}
```

The method that you've provided will not work as expected. The loop terminate on the first step of iteration without checking all element, i.e. it can potentially return an incorrect result, and you will and up with duplicates in the list.

Double equals sign should be used only if you want to check whether two references point to the same object, otherwise use method `equelst()` to determine the equality of objects.